# Sequelize Connection error - authSwitch.authSwitchRequest is not a function

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I'm running my sql in docker container and was using it to run the test cases. All of a sudden I've started facing this error:

```
SequelizeConnectionError: authSwitch.authSwitchRequest is not a function
```

and it is randomly breaking the test cases. What I've tried so far is:

- Tried to investigate the connection (no luck)
- Updated the sequelize version to the latest one

Sequelize version I'm running on is `6.6.2`

Comment: did you solve ?